# Adding lists to a nested list dictionary

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I'm trying to create and fill a dictionary that contains a list as it's value; i.e.

```
Dictionary <string, List<string>> DictionaryA = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>();
```

The values in the dictionary are then going to be output into an Excel spreadsheet.

The issue arises when I am trying to input lists into the Dictionary under a Key. The first Dictionary assignment is fine, for example a list of 10 strings under the Key "Key1".

```
Dictionary <string, List<string>> DictionaryA = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
int i = 0;
while(page.MoveNext()) //For example, for each page in a book
{
  while(words.MoveNext()) //For example, words in the page
  {
    if(!(ListA.Contains(ValueA)) //For example, we are looking to store instances of each word in each page of a book
    {
       ListA.Add(ValueA);
    }
    DictionaryA.Add(i, ListA);
    i++;
  }

  sortedList = DictionaryA.Keys.ToList(); //Let's say we want to sort the Dictionary as well
  sortedList.Sort()

  foreach (var key in sortedList)
  {
    DictionaryASorted.Add(key, DictionaryA[key]);
  }

  ExcelOuput(DictionaryASorted); //Function to export and save an Excel File
}
```

So the first run through page.Movenext() loop is fine, the Dictionary is filled correctly with the list. However, on the second run through of the loop, any unique "ValueA" that is found is added to the list "ListA" - this modifies the "ListA" that is already stored in the Dictionary. The end result is a Dictionary that contains the different page numbers as keys, and the same huge List of words for each of those keys.

If I use `ListA.Clear()` at the beginning of each page loop, the List ends up being the words from the last page it reads and nothing else.

How can I use this nested List without changing the previous List being modified? Am I trying to do this the right way? Or is there a better, more elegant solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to creat a new list in the loop.

So, just above `while(words.MoveNext())`

You need:

```
List<string> ListA = new List<string>();
```

This will create a new list for you to populate.  You have to realize that the dictionary and ListA are both pointing at the same list.  Adding or clearing the list does the same to the list the dictionary refferences.  You need to create a new list for each dictionary value.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, thanks a lot! Why didn't I see that before?! Gah!

Comment: @Eomo Classic issue.  Don't feel bad.  It can be hard to tell when a variable is passed by value or by reference when you add it to another object.